# Generating PHP class files from a .proto file for an protocolbuffer problems

Tags: php

**Question**
Does anyone know how to correctly create php classes from the proto files of a protocol buffer on a mac (10.7.5). Or on any other machine.
Or could anyone simply give me these for the metro lines in Amsterdam, San Fransico and Vienna?

**Context**
After some days work installing [ibprotoc 2.4.1](https://github.com/drslump/Protobuf-PHP#readme) (because newer versions gave me another error during generation) pear homebrew etcetera, I have not managed to create a working class file.
I dowloaded correct working class files for MTA (github.com/pnf/mta) from this guy (dougla...gmail.com on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mtadeveloperresources/php/mtadeveloperresources/k2Pl7WdGPRg/4W4koGrJxnsJ) , but I am not able to produce the same results for the other cities, or to replicate these files for MTA.

We need these clases for an interactive art project.

**my efforts so far**
When I use the correct proto files from MTA I can run

```
protoc-gen-php -i . nyct-subway.proto
```

which gives me the class files but while doing so generating multiple errors like

> WARNING: Non tracked package name found "TripReplacementPeriod"

Running my php programm (fetching the buffers and converting them with these classes) gives me the error

> PHP Warning:  First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class

Which does not surprise me of course ...